# Concatenate a variable as a input name inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate the value 'row' inside this function but is not working properly, im trying to pass the string value of row on the input name.

```
    var row = 'm_89375312';
$("input[name='" + row + "']").change(function () {
    var max = 3;
    if ($("input[name='" + row + "']:checked").length == max) {
        $("input[name='" + row + "']:checked").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("input[name='" + row + "']:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $("input[name='" + row + "']:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
})
```

Am I doing the concatenation wrong?

Comment: post your html as well

Comment: What's the goal of the code in the `if` block?

Comment: The 'if' verify and limits the number of checkbox the user checks by 3, if the user checks more than that disables the other checks of that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concatenation is just fine, although it would be better not to repeat it like that. Also, use `prop`, not `attr`, to set/clear props like `disabled`: `.prop("disabled", true")` and `.prop("disabled", false)`.

I'm going to guess that you want to disable all of the UNchecked matches for that name when `max` boxes are checked, and enable them all when `max` boxes are not checked. If so:

```
var row = "m_89375312";
var rowSelector = "input[name='" + row + "']";
$(rowSelector).change(function () {
    var max = 3;
    if ($(rowSelector + ":checked").length == max) {
        // Disable the ones that aren't checked yet
        $(rowSelector + ":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        // Re-enable any that used to be disabled
        $(rowSelector).prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

Live Example:

```js
var row = "m_89375312";
var rowSelector = "input[name='" + row + "']";
$(rowSelector).change(function () {
    var max = 3;
    if ($(rowSelector + ":checked").length == max) {
        // Disable the ones that aren't checked yet
        $(rowSelector + ":not(:checked)").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        // Re-enable any that used to be disabled
        $(rowSelector).prop("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="m_89375312">
        A
      </label>
</div>
<div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="m_89375312">
        B
      </label>
</div>
<div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="m_89375312">
        C
      </label>
</div>
<div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="m_89375312">
        D
      </label>
</div>
<div>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="m_89375312">
        E
      </label>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

In modern environments, I'd also probably use an ES2015+ template literal instead of string concatenation:

```
const rowSelector = `input[name="${row}"]`;
```